# Generate random date in specific range in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

For testing one of my application I need some huge data in parquet format. which I don't have.I have written a shell script which is performing slow.I wanted go with spark.How can I generate random data using spark scala.
Each filed has to be in specific range.Id should be in between (1-10),date(any date from 2010-2018),start and end time should be any.
My shell scipt.

## !/bin/bash

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    LIMIT=40  # to generate 40KB file
    for((i=0;i<$2;i++))
    {
        FILE_NAME="$1$i.csv"
        echo "id,date,start_time,end_time,distance,amount,persons,longitude,latitude" >> "$FILE_NAME"
        while [ $(du -k $FILE_NAME | cut -f 1) -le $LIMIT ]
        do
            start_time=`date -d "$(date +%H:%M:%S) + $(shuf -i 0-24 -n 1) hours $(shuf -i 0-60 -n 1) minutes $(shuf -i 0-60 -n 1) seconds" +'%H:%M:%S'`
            echo "`shuf -i 1-10 -n 1`,`date -d "2011-01-01 + $(shuf -i 1-2557 -n 1) days" +'%m-%d-%Y'`,$start_time,`date -d "$start_time + $(shuf -i 1-6 -n 1) hours $(shuf -i 0-60 -n 1) minutes $(shuf -i 0-60 -n 1) seconds" +'%H:%M:%S'`,`shuf -i 1-60 -n 1`,`shuf -i 100-1500 -n 1`,`shuf -i 1-6 -n 1`,`shuf -i 10-99 -n 1`.`shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1`,`shuf -i 10-99 -n 1`.`shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1`" >> "$FILE_NAME"
        done
    }
else
    printf "Usage: sh GenerateCSV.sh <filename without extension> <No of files to generate> \nThe files will be generated with .csv extension\n" 
fi
```

I want data to be like this,which should be parquet format.

```
2,20-10-2010,23:18:10,23:40:40
```

How can I do it in spark.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option.
Below are the Unix Timestamp values for the dates mentioned.

```
val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("local").master("local[*]").getOrCreate() 

ss.sqlContext.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp ('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')") // 1262284200
ss.sqlContext.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp ('2018-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')") // 1546194600
```

You can code in this below way for generating random number between the above numbers.

```
val r = new scala.util.Random
val x = 1262284200 + r.nextInt((1546194600-1262284200))
```

You can code in this below way for generating random date between the dates by using above generated value `x`

```
ss.sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME($x)")
```